# Actionscript 3 and nested lists

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have the following code in my XML (EDIT:) which I am trying to show in a RichText using htmlText.

```
<ul>
<li>List Item 1
   <ul>
      <li>List Item 2</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, Flash doesn't seem to support nested lists, and I am getting output which looks like this:

- List item 1
- List item 2

Where I want the second ul to be indented further.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Are we talking about Richtext fields that renders HTML within Flash or where is this problem?

Comment: Sorry, my question was really unclear. I have edited my post.

Comment: Good, last thing. What version of Flash do you use? Actionscript 3, is it Flashplayer v9.0 or v10.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

**have you tried:**

```
<ul>
   <li>List Item 1
      <ul>
         <li>List Item 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

As far as I know, nested UL's should be within LI-tags

Comment: This looks EXACTLY like the code in the original question. Am I missing something? The only difference appears to be the number of spaces indenting the tags...

Comment: Hmm, I was sure that your bulletlist wasn't structed with tags like I mentioned here. I saw it as [li]List Item 1[/li]. Will have an extra look at it though.

Answer (score 0):

I usually "debug" my output by using special CSS for that kinda stuff.

What if you add a class/style to some of the items, eg. make

```
ul {border:solid 1px #f00;}
```

to build a nice red border around each UL group and see if you get one or two red rectangles. Then we know if it detects/renders UL no. 2.

If it does, then I would make another CSS test to see if I could get a green one inside the red one:

```
ul li ul {border:solid 1px #0f0;}
```

If that works, then you could try to add some margin-left:20px to the second test.